# Forecasting a not-seasonal time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, prediction

I would to forecast a not-seasonal time serie in R. This is my serie and the model built with HoltWinters:

```
tsRedditoMedioForecast <- HoltWinters(redditoMedio, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
```

If beta and gamma parameters are FALSE, I built a Brown model that haven't seasonal component.

[image: Time series and model with HoltWinters]

For forecasting, I imported the library "forecast" in my workspace:

```
install.packages('forecast', dependencies = TRUE)
library('forecast')
```

Last step: I would to forecast and calculate the value for the next 10 units. I put this R code:

```
tsRedditoMedioForecast2 <- forecast(tsRedditoMedioForecast, h=10)
plot(tsRedditoMedioForecast2)
```

The result is this:
[image: Forecasting time series]
But I don't expect this. Time serie is increasing, so I expect an increasing prediction line. Not an horizontal constant line. What's the problem?

**UPDATE**

I have expected results with **ETS** and **auto.arima models**

[image]

Why not with HoltWinters?

Comment: Do you expect a moving average to project a trend?  If so, please see [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Double_exponential_smoothing) remark "Simple exponential smoothing does not do well when there is a trend in the data" and the subsequent passages.

Comment: Thanks. I introduce the trend component with beta factor in HoltWinters function:
tsRedditoMedioForecast <- HoltWinters(redditoMedio, beta=TRUE, gamma=FALSE)
And now I have my prediction line

Answer (score 0):

I put the trend component in my model and it works! Thansk whuber

```
tsRedditoMedioForecast <- HoltWinters(redditoMedio, beta=TRUE, gamma=FALSE)
```